# How to pass a function argument into the jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I have a site with several pop up windows. I want to use 1 single function on several elements. It works well in regular JS, but not in jQuery.

In my HTML I have something like:

```
<button onclick="div_show('contact')">More?</button>
```

and

```
<div id="contact" >
    blah blah
</div>
```

This #contact element is hidden by default. So if i click on the button the contact div appears with this JS:

```
    function div_show(id) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

However, i want to use jquery for the fade effects

```
function div_show(id) {
$(???).fadeIn();
}
```

How can i make the function argument to pass into the jquery selector

It works well like this of course :

```
function div_show(id) {
    $(#contact).fadeIn();
    }
```

but works only for 1 element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
$("#" + id).fadeIn();
```

For multiple selectors you could do this:

```
$("#" + id1 + ", #" + id2).fadeIn(); //etc
```

Also for completeness, this line:

```
 $(#contact).fadeIn();
```

should be formatted with quotes:

```
 $("#contact").fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function div_show(id) {
 $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
```